# Ветка Git это указатель или ветка?

Tags: git, git-branch

Не понимаю как представить ветку. В некоторых источниках ветка выглядит как ветка, а другие говорят что это указатель на коммит.

Вариант 1:

[image: вариант1]

Вариант 2:

[image: вариант2]

Comment: А вы первоисточник читали? https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: это указатель на коммит.  ваше воображение может продлить его до "ветки" (цепочки коммитов), но фактически информация о том, где раньше проходила эта ветка, гитом уже утеряна, иногда приходится угадывать по комментам коммитов, а потом понимаешь что у разных разработчиков эта ветка шла разными путями, и само понятие "ветки" оказывается неопределённым. вот то ли дело в SVN и ему подобных - там всё ясно )))

Comment: Git в целом это своеобразная файловая система. Ты туда закидываешь файл и в таблице указателей появляется на него указатель. Закидываешь второй и появляется указатель на второй файл и на первый указатель. Перемещение файлов, удаление и т.д. приводят к новым указателям. Советую почитать gitbook https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-изнутри-Сантехника-и-Фарфор

Comment: «Вариант 1» это просто когда какие-то два коммита имеют один и тот же родительский коммит. К веткам это в целом не имеет отношения, ветки как были просто указателями, так ими и остаются

Answer (score 2):

Git предстаавляем собой направленный граф, который состоит из узлов (коммитов) и связей между узлами.

В Git также можно сделать именованную ссылку на коммит (например, `master`). То есть это ссылка, которая 1) имеет имя 2) может указывать на разные коммиты в разное время.

Веткой принято обычно называть либо эту именованную ссылку (указывающую на какой то коммит), либо путь от коммита, на который она указыват, до самого первого коммита в репозитории.